# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadpool, nullreferenceexception, httpcontext

Why I'm getting this error. My variables get the names from request, and also i tried "data.qext" but visual studio give me error.

I got "test.pdf" file in my WebsiteRoot/uploads/files/test.pdf, but still there is an error. Maybe I'm missing something?

Check image for detailed description: http://prntscr.com/7wnid

Comment: Do you have an HttpContext? Looks like you HttpContext.Current.Sever is null...

Comment: If you mean about this, yes ofc i have http://prntscr.com/7wnrc

Comment: I mean... when you debug, if you pass your mouse over HttpContext.Current.Sever... does it show something or is it null?

Comment: Oh wow, i noticed that but i throw it cant be my error since i never got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method instead of `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()
```

Doing so, there's no need for an `HttpContext`.

Comment: Since i got my error with HttpContext.Current.Sever.MapPath inside my other functions, this definitely solve my problem. THANKS!